# Adobe photoshop "not enough ram" message opening a 60 MB TIFF file

Tags: memory, performance, adobe-photoshop, compression, tiff

I am working with Windows 7 x64 on a full HD monitor, Intel i5-2500K and 8 GB RAM, currently available 5,5GB. I tried to extend photoshop's memory usage and scratch disk settings as following:

[image: Photoshop performance settings]

But as I try to open a 60MB TIFF file with compression, dimensions 7040x9860 (resulted by scanning with 1200ppi) I still get the mentioned message:

[image: Error message]

Why are 5,5 GB not enough to open a 60 MB file? I don't have any clues!

**Update:** I understand that 60 MB compressed would take much more place after decompression, which must be done by opening the file. That's why a just tried the following: I scanned the same document but chose uncompressed TIFF. The resulted file is approximately 200 MB and it can be opened by Photoshop! Well this causes more confusion...

**Update 2:** Here's the Photoshop's about dialog for those who are asking:

[image]

Comment: Could you give an exact translation of the error message into english please?

Comment: The 60MB file is compressed. Uncompressed it will use much more memory (almost ideally it will use 264.75MiB, but with multiple layers this it could need much much worse. 

(Logic for 264MiB: 1) 

1) You mention 7040x9860.  

2) 7040x9860 is 69414400 pixels.  

3) Assuming 4 bytes per data (For R, G, B and alfa channel) and you need:
69414400 pixels * 4 bytes = 277657600 bytes

4) That is a large number, lets make it a bit more readable:  
277657600 bytes is 277657600/1024 KiB (271.150KiB)  which is 264.75MiB.

Comment: Error translated: "Could not progress because there is insufficient memory (RAM) available"

Comment: I suspect this is more about the virtual memory then the physical memory.  This the same machine the file was created on?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it's the same PC. I just scanned a picture on a MFP and wanted to open it.

Comment: What's the version reported in the About dialog?

Comment: @and31415 Please see the updated question.

Comment: Latest version is `12.0.4`. Close Photoshop, install the [update](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5076), and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on an 8GB machine and a 12GB machine with a 12MB TIFF using PsE. I opened the file in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) which told me the file had a "bad null bit" (but opened it anyway). I exported this image back to hard drive with a new filename, and this GIMP output opened in Adobe fine.

Comment: I expect that this (file corruption) was the issue, in light of the fact the OP was able to open a different version of the scan using the same workflow. Certainly the pixel dimensions and 200MB memory footprint are both supported by Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

No definite answer, but some things to ponder on:

1. Compression, may require immense amounts of extra RAM temporarily.
   --> This might be something allocated OUTSIDE Ps's memory realm; if you reserve all memory for Ps - then there is none to get.
2. I assume C:\ is your system- and software installation-disk.

   a) Reorder your temporary folders; make D:\ be used first or "only"
   --> better leave the system disk as a "last option".

   b) make Windows swapfile appear on D:\ - not C:\ - the swapfile may well eat up all 10 GB in memory hungry operations
   --> At least older Windows versions has a habit of misbehaving severely in that situation.